# How do I add time datatype column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in sql server 2012,with column named Duration as Time datatype.i want to update this column base on difference of dates, by adding the difference to this duration column.how can I do this in SP.

```
ID    StartDate               EndDate                 Duration
1     2017-02-27 09:10:35     2017-02-27 09:25:35      00:15
2     2017-02-27 09:26:35   2017-02-27 09:36:35        00:25
```

Durtion always less than 24 hours.

Comment: The key piece you don't explicitly state is that you appear to want duration to sum prior IDs as part of the Duration value. You need to clarify that.

Comment: I want to get difference in date as hh:mm in term of sum on each new row

Comment: The accepted answer does not sum the duration, so I don't understand why you accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
update t
    set duration = cast(dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, startdate, enddate), 0) as time);
```

Comment: Hey, Gordon.  In an effort to improve myself, I'm hoping you can tell me what was wrong with my arithmetic approach? It returns valid answers here, but I got a down vote - so I'm assuming that something is wrong with it.  Any explanation you could offer?

Comment: Actually, upon checking your response, I get an error...`Explicit conversion from data type int to time is not allowed. (SQLSTATE=22018) (529) (Severity=16) (MsgState=2)`... Thought you might want to know? Hope I'm not overstepping...

Comment: Getting rid of the cast(0 as time) and making it 0 solves that error

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy one. Just use a simple arithmetic operation:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (Start DATETIME, Finish DATETIME, Duration TIME);

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 08:00','02/28/2017 08:30','');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 09:00','02/28/2017 09:40','');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 10:02','02/28/2017 11:53','');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 11:56','02/28/2017 12:45','');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 13:45','02/28/2017 23:59','');

UPDATE @TABLE
SET Duration = Finish - Start;

SELECT * FROM @TABLE;
```

Returns:

```
Start                    Finish                 Duration
---------------------------------------------------------
28/02/2017 08:00:00      28/02/2017 08:30:00    00:30:00
28/02/2017 09:00:00      28/02/2017 09:40:00    00:40:00
28/02/2017 10:02:00      28/02/2017 11:53:00    01:51:00
28/02/2017 11:56:00      28/02/2017 12:45:00    00:49:00
28/02/2017 13:45:00      28/02/2017 23:59:00    10:14:00
```

The only caveat here being that they need to be on the same day.  You explicitly stated that the duration is never more than one day, so that should be fine.

If you want to add the result to the original value of `Duration`, then you would just add it on...

```
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/27/2017 08:00','02/28/2017 08:30','00:15');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 09:00','02/28/2017 09:40','00:14');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 10:02','02/28/2017 11:53','00:13');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 11:56','02/28/2017 12:45','02:16');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES ('02/28/2017 13:45','02/28/2017 23:59','00:17');

UPDATE @TABLE
SET Duration = Duration + (Finish - Start);
```

Returns:

```
Start                    Finish                 Duration
---------------------------------------------------------   
27/02/2017 08:00:00      28/02/2017 08:30:00    00:45:00
28/02/2017 09:00:00      28/02/2017 09:40:00    00:54:00
28/02/2017 10:02:00      28/02/2017 11:53:00    02:04:00
28/02/2017 11:56:00      28/02/2017 12:45:00    03:05:00
28/02/2017 13:45:00      28/02/2017 23:59:00    10:31:00
```

Comment: Judging from the down vote, I apparently misunderstood the question...?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE [TABLE] SET [DURATION] = CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartDate, EndDate), 0), 114);

Comment: DECLARE @t TIME
SELECT @t = CONVERT(varchar(5),DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2017-02-22 17:03:40.757', '2017-02-22 17:04:30.580'), 0), 114)
SELECT @t

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers attempt to SUM the duration which is what you expect.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, StartTime DATETIME, EndTime DATETIME, Duration TIME);

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (1, '02/28/2017 01:00','02/28/2017 06:30','');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (2, '02/28/2017 09:00','02/28/2017 23:40','');
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES (3, '03/01/2017 10:02','03/01/2017 21:53','');

UPDATE t
SET Duration=
    CONVERT(TIME,
        (
            SELECT DATEADD(ms, SUM(DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00.000', EndTime - StartTime)), '00:00:00.000')
            FROM @TABLE it
            WHERE it.EndTime<= t.EndTime
        )
    )
FROM @TABLE t;

SELECT * FROM @TABLE;
```